# Implementing a evaluation system using jekyll

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I am improving a website that was created using Jekyll. This site is a blog for an enterprise, and there are some texts there. I need a plugin, which let the readers evaluate the texts. However, I haven't found any.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This Jekyll site (I created) uses a rating form:
http://www.stresan.de/perfekte-turniervorbereitung/

The code below relies on some Javascript and a form that is submitted through the CloudCannon form handling. Cloudcannon can easily be replaced by some other form service, like FormSpree, FormSubmit, FormBucket or others. The initial value of the post is set in the Front Matter. This rating system is therefore partially fake, but it provides good feedback.

```js
function setreviewval(val){
    var i=1;
 $('#review img').each(function(){
  if(i<=val) $(this).attr('src','http://www.stresan.de/img/star.svg');
  else $(this).attr('src','http://www.stresan.de/img/star-empty.svg');
  i++;
 }); 
}
function setreviewvaldef(val){
 setreviewval(val);
 //remove mouseover and mouseout
 $('#review img').attr('onmouseover','');
 $('#review img').attr('onmouseout','');
}
```

```css
img {width: 30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="review"><div>Bewerte diesen Artikel: </div>
<img src="http://www.stresan.de/img/star.svg" onmouseover="setreviewval(1);" onmouseout="setreviewval(4);" onclick="setreviewvaldef(1);$('#rating').val(1);$('#ratingform').show().attr('action',$('#ratingform').attr('action')+'#rating=1');" />
<img src="http://www.stresan.de/img/star.svg" onmouseover="setreviewval(2);" onmouseout="setreviewval(4);" onclick="setreviewvaldef(2);$('#rating').val(2);$('#ratingform').show().attr('action',$('#ratingform').attr('action')+'#rating=2');" />
<img src="http://www.stresan.de/img/star.svg" onmouseover="setreviewval(3);" onmouseout="setreviewval(4);" onclick="setreviewvaldef(3);$('#rating').val(3);$('#ratingform').show().attr('action',$('#ratingform').attr('action')+'#rating=3');" />
<img src="http://www.stresan.de/img/star.svg" onmouseover="setreviewval(4);" onmouseout="setreviewval(4);" onclick="setreviewvaldef(4);$('#rating').val(4);$('#ratingform').show().attr('action',$('#ratingform').attr('action')+'#rating=4');" />
<img src="http://www.stresan.de/img/star-empty.svg" onmouseover="setreviewval(5);" onmouseout="setreviewval(4);" onclick="setreviewvaldef(5);$('#rating').val(5);$('#ratingform').show().attr('action',$('#ratingform').attr('action')+'#rating=5');" />
<form method="POST" id="ratingform" action="{{ page.url }}"><input type="hidden" name="_to" value="jhvanderschee@gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="post" value="{{ page.url }}" /><input id="rating" type="hidden" name="rating" value="" /><br />
<input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Please clarify your score..." class="form-control" required="required" />
</form>
</div>
```